# scan QR codes into bluestacks android apps with PC webcam

Tags: windows-10, smartphone, bluestacks, qr-code

This is not an android question. 
It is a bluestacks question.

I do not own a smart phone.

For android apps i use bluestacks installed on windows 10 pro.

i ordered a smart watch from aliexpress.

it requires me to scan a QR code into an android/ios device in order to pair.

(How)Can I use my pc webcam to scan QR codes into android apps on bluestacks ?

Comment: Old post (with no answer), but as it turns out, I have the exact same question.  Any takers?